# How in React JSX to pass a parent custom react component state attribute value to child customer component?

Tags: reactjs

How in React JSX to pass a parent custom react component state attribute value to child customer component?

Assume the MyCustomRectComponentA component has a state variable "offset".  How then to get access to this to pass as a prop to AnotherCustomComponentB?

```
  public render() {
    return (
      <MyCustomRectComponentA>
        <AnotherCustomComponentB offsetValue={parent.state.offset} />
      </MyCustomRectComponentA>
    );

  }
```

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - just checking - in the JSX extract is actually from JSX component 1 say.  Within the render method I have the JSX component 2 tag (MyCustomRectComponentA), which within it has JSX component 3 (AnotherCustomComponentB).  So normally "this" would refer to JSX component 1 and not component 2 (/MyCustomRectComponentA)?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That's not what's being asked for.

Comment: @DaveNewton My mistake, the question wasn't quite clear to me

Comment: @Greg do you want to access offset in MyCustomRectComponentA??

Comment: yes @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670173/accessing-react-component-children-props-from-the-parent. However I would say, you could simply pass offset to MyCustomRectComponentA unless you want to access all props of children purposefully

Comment: @Greg you want to pass `MyCustomRectComponentA` (2)component state as props  to `AnotherCustomComponentB`(3)  and they both are in another parent component (1)

Comment: @JSEngine - Yes they are in another custom parent component.

Comment: ok then you  can use `React.children` and `React.cloneElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.Children` and `React.cloneElement` api in your `MyCustomRectComponentA` component.

eg:

```
import React, { Component, Children , cloneElement } from 'react'

class MyCustomRectComponentA extends Component {
    state = {
        offset: '50px'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>              
                // mapping through every children elements
                // passed to "MyCustomRectComponentA" component
                {Children.map(this.props.children, child => { 
                    // you have to clone the child element
                    // because they are read-only 
                    // and pass the "state" as props
                    return cloneElement(child, {
                     offsetValue: this.state.offset 
                    })
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default MyCustomRectComponentA
```

After this you can update your parent component containing `MyCustomRectComponentA` and `AnotherCustomComponentB` to

```
 public render() {
    return (
      <MyCustomRectComponentA>
        <AnotherCustomComponentB />
      </MyCustomRectComponentA>
    );

  }
```

What we have done is that we passed `<AnotherCustomComponentB />` component as children to `</MyCustomRectComponentA>` component.

And in `</MyCustomRectComponentA>` component

1) we mapped through children component passed to it

2) cloned the children component

3) passed state "offset" as props to children component

For more detail about `React.Children` you can go to this [source](https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/)