# Access children props before render

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children, react-props

I'm building a Wizard/Steps component where every child component is a step, the Steps component find the current step that should be show and renders it wrapped in a provider.

I next step I want to achieve is a component to be rendered during all steps. I achieve through the child components props before be render, so that way I could work with the components like this:

```
    <Steps >
        <Text> Step 1 </Text> 
        <Text> Step 2 </Text>
        <Text stepless > Stepless </Text>
    </Steps>
```

I achieve it by coding Steps component like this.

```
export const Steps: React.FC<types.Steps> = ({ step = 0, ...properties }) => {

    /**
     * Global state that store the total number of steps and the current step
     */
    const steps = React.Children.count(properties.children)
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { step, steps })

    /**
     * Function that will let child components to change the current step
     */
    const next = () => dispatch(types.Action.NEXT)
    const previous = () => dispatch(types.Action.PREVIOUS)

    /**
     * Value to provide to the provider
     * next and previous function to change the current step
     * and the current step
     */
    const value = { next, previous, step: state.step }

    /**
     * Filter the child components that should be shown
     */
    const children = React.Children.toArray(properties.children)
        .filter((child, index) =>
            // @ts-ignore
            (index === state.step) || child?.props.stepless
        )

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={value} >
            { children.map((child, index) => <div key={ index } > { child } </div>) }
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

But this code smells to me because `child?.props` is not part of the types of react, this make me believe that is used internally and I not should be using it, but I not found other solution to filter components that should be shown over all the steps.

I'm looking for a different way to achieve the same behavior, without using `//@ts-ignore`.

Comment: What about `React.isValidElement(element)`, [refer QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670173/accessing-react-component-children-props-from-the-parent)