# How does a marker in 'google-map-react' get its location based on latitude and longitude from props?

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react, the marker on the map get its location on the map from the longitude and latitude from props.

```
import React from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

export default function SimpleMap(){
  const defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 10.99835602,
      lng: 77.01502627
    },
    zoom: 11
  };

  return (
    // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "" }}
        defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
        defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
      >
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={59.955413}
          lng={30.337844}
          text="My Marker"
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the case, `AnyReactComponent` is the marker on the map. However, based on the component defined above the SimpleMap component, it doesn't take 'lag' and 'lng' as props. the only prop it takes is "text". However, if I give this 'AnyReactComponent' component's lat and lng a value as props. How does this "AnyReactComponent" change its location with these two given props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [example](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/tree/master/example):

[Marker](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/example/src/components/Marker.js#L22) never declare the props
but they are used anyway when component is created in [App](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/example/src/App.js#L40)

`GoogleMapReact` just gets the `lat` and `lng` [props from the child](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/src/google_map_markers.js#L273)

[How to access child's props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670173/accessing-react-component-children-props-from-the-parent)